# Grails use the java swing library for the gsp

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a question regrading my simple grails application and I'm just wondering if I can use the swing library provided by the java to be use in grails for designing my interface, And I don't know if this is possible, but if it's possible it will make my life easy in putting objects especially object like grid table that swing can only do to be put on my gsp file. Any comments suggestion will really be appreacited.

Comment: I thought so... do you have any idea on how can I create a listview or a gridview perhaps?

Comment: If you want to simplify your life with UI, you can try Twitter Bootstrap (Foundation 3, Boilerplate, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop with Swing and use benefits such as the ones Grails provides you should look into Griffon (http://griffon.codehaus.org/) which is a Grails-like RIA platform. 
Alternatively you may want to use other Swing-like java frameworks which can be used for web-development. The most notable are Google Web Toolkit (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) and Vaadin (https://vaadin.com/home). Grails has plugins for both of them.

Comment: I believe he wants a tool to convert a Swing layout to a gsp file

Comment: yep... a converter tool from swing to gsp file.